# Ставится ли запятая перед союзом "а"?

Tags: пунктуация, грамматика, запятые

Предложение "Не тот() а этот".
Ставится ли здесь запятая и почему?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Ставится ли запятая после буквы “а”?

Запятая разделяет не буквы, а слова (в данном случае *а* - это союз). В данном случае она ставится не после союза *а*, а перед ним.

**Не тот, а этот.**

> [§ 144. Запятая ставится между однородными членами предложения](http://n-t.ru/ac/56/pz03.htm), соединёнными посредством союзов а, но, да (в значении «но»), однако, хотя и т.п., например: Не род, а ум поставлю в воеводы (Пушкин).

Примеры из Нацкорпуса:

> Правда, в Сербии мне пришлось слышать доклад одного из добровольцев-офицеров, Туган-Барановского, который объяснял неудачи наши именно какими-то неверными военными действиями: вот если бы не так, а так… да если бы **не то, а это**… тогда бы… [Митрополит Вениамин (Федченков). На рубеже двух эпох (1940-1950)]
>
> И порешили, что ситняки все же **не те, а эти**, ближние. [Евгений Носов. Усвятские шлемоносцы (1977)]